# ID: kids' novel, alternate universes, suits designed by disappeared father

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, childrens-novel, parallel-universe

I'm trying to identify a English-language kids' SF novel, I would have read this as a library hardcover some time before 1980. To the best of my recollection:

- Protagonists were subadult brother and sister.
- Father was scientist, had disappeared as novel opened.
- Father had left behind two suits — like spacesuits? — which, when you put the suit on and changed a control — a knob, maybe? — transferred you to an alternate universe. Or maybe only one suit.
- Some alternate universe was presumably where the father had disappeared to, and the siblings were off to find him.
- The father and the kids were on the run from government agents who wanted the technology.
- Kids couldn't control — or didn't know how to control — where they would go.

The cover may have been primarily grey. And any of these bullet points could be wrong. (It's been a while!) I'm most solid about the father, the kids, and the suits.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Except for the suits, this bears some resemblance to Madeleine L'Engel's *A Stitch in Time*...

Comment: @ZeissIkon I think you mean *A **Wrinkle** in Time*, but yes, the absent father and young siblings searching for him is very similar.

Comment: @ZeissIkon quite true. But definitely not that, as I read _A Wrinkle In Time_ many times during those same years.

Comment: @DavidW You are correct.